# Pandas: Create DF with custom columns based on different DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes and need to either alter the second to fit the format of my first or I can create a new dataframe altogether.

The first dataframe is simply...

```
stores_df = pd.DataFrame({'Stores': ['Kroger', 'United'], 'City':['Dallas','Austin']})

    Stores  City
0   Kroger  Dallas
1   United  Austin
```

The second is formatted like so (this is how it is given to me, I can't change it)...

```
apples_df = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow','Red', 'Green', 'Yellow'], 'Store':['Kroger','Kroger','Kroger','United','United','United'], 'Ripe': ['20','17', '14', '23', '18', '0']})

    Color   Stores  Ripe
0   Red     Kroger  20
1   Green   Kroger  17
2   Yellow  Kroger  14
3   Red     United  23
4   Green   United  18
5   Yellow  United  0
```

My desired dataframe is the combination of both, except color value + column header 'Ripe' becomes the destination's column header and the count is added to each of the first dataframe's store row. Like so...

```
    Stores  City    Red Ripe    Green Ripe    Yellow Ripe
0   Kroger  Dallas  20          17            14
1   United  Austin  23          18            0
```

I'm somewhat familiar with merging/joining and messed around with pivot tables enough to realize I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, `merge` two df, the do long to wide reshape by `unstack`

```
stores_df.merge(apples_df,left_on='Stores',right_on='Store').\ 
   set_index(['Stores','City','Color'])['Ripe'].\
        unstack().\
         add_suffix(' Ripe').\
           reset_index()
Out[194]: 
Color  Stores    City Green Ripe Red Ripe Yellow Ripe
0      Kroger  Dallas         17       20          14
1      United  Austin         18       23           0
```

Comment: Random downvote without comment=> I upvote. ~ following jpp's philosophy :)

Comment: @HarvIpan thank you man :-) . I am just curious about the reason , which may help me improve ,sign .

Answer (score 2):

#### pivot_table + merge

A couple of steps: pivot `apples_df` and then merge with `stores_df`.

```
apples_pvt = apples_df.pivot_table(index='Store', columns='Color',
                                   values='Ripe', aggfunc='sum')

res = stores_df.merge(apples_pvt.add_suffix(' Ripe'), left_on='Stores', right_index=True)

print(res)

   Stores    City Green Ripe Red Ripe Yellow Ripe
0  Kroger  Dallas         17       20          14
1  United  Austin         18       23           0
```

Comment: How would I add the Suffix "-Ripe" to the column headers in this case? So they'd read "Red-Ripe" etc...